# Iterating dict.items() when passed to Pool map function gives weird results

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to do some multiprocessing in Python 3. I found something weird when trying to iterate over dict items that are passed through the Pool.map() method from the multiprocessing module.

```
from multiprocessing.pool import Pool

def reduce(lines):
    print(lines[0])

pool = Pool(processes=8)
dataset = [(1, {"foo": "bar"}), (2, {"foo": "bar"})]
print(dataset[0])
a = pool.map(reduce, dataset)
```

As you can see here, the `print(dataset[0])` will print :

```
(1, {'foo': 'bar'})
```

While the print(lines[0]) will print :

```
1
2
```

Is this behaviour normal or am I missing something ? If I am, is there a way to bypass that ?

Comment: unrelated: `reduce()` might cause confusion with `functools.reduce()`. `reduce()` was a builtin function in Python 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It behaves as it should: `lines == (1, {"foo": "bar"})` i.e., `lines` is an *item* in the `dataset` list -- it is not the list itself. `pool.map()` behaves as an ordinary map in this regard:

```
squares = list(map(lambda item: item*item, [1, 2, 3]))
# -> [1, 4, 9]
```

Comment: Thanks! But I can't figure out how to access the data like it does when outside the reduce (ie. as when calling dataset[0]). Would you know a way ?

Comment: Oh i get it ! If I change my reduce function this way : def reduce(lines):
    print(lines)
    print("break")

I will get the word "break" between each line. Thanks